Add new property to existing response schema in OpenAPI 3.0.x
I have four paths a,b,c,d.all paths have same properties and schemas previously.Now there is a new requirement where paths c & d will have change in the property called rex.Positioning is important here how can i achieve this.
as we can see the response 200 ref is same for all four paths but for path-c & d for certain propert called rex i need to override the existing way how its defined.
{
  "paths": {
    "/example/version/path-a": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "Get Details by path a",
        "tags": [
          "GET"
        ],
        "operationId": "",
        "description": "",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/parameters/path-a"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/parameters/auth"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/200-get"
          },
          "400": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/400-get"
          },
          "404": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/404-get"
          },
          "500": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/500-get"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/example/version/path-b": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "Get Details by path-b",
        "tags": [
          "GET"
        ],
        "operationId": "",
        "description": "",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/parameters/auth"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/parameters/path-b"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/200-get"
          },
          "400": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/400-get"
          },
          "404": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/404-get"
          },
          "500": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/500-get"
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "forge-token": []
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "/example/version/path-c/": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "Get by path c",
        "tags": [
          "GET"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/200-get"
          },
          "400": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/400-get"
          },
          "404": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/404-get"
          },
          "500": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/500-get"
          }
        },
        "operationId": "",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/parameters/path-c"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/parameters/auth"
          }
        ],
        "description": ""
      }
    },
    "exmple/version/path-d": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "Get details by d",
        "tags": [
          "GET"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/200-get"
          },
          "400": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/400-get"
          },
          "404": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/404-get"
          },
          "500": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/500-get"
          }
        },
        "operationId": "",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/parameters/path-d"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/parameters/auth"
          }
        ],
        "description": ""
      }
    }
  }
}


define a new response schema and reference it with allOf
{
  "components": {
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "OK",
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/original_schema"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "200-updated": {
        "description": "this response has the new property and the old property",
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "allOf": [
                {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/original_schema"
                },
                {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/new_schema"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "schemas": {
      "original_schema": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "new_schema": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "age": {
            "type": "number"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


